# How to disable loading schema.sql if database already exists?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am using H2 database stored in a file and schema.sql script to initialize the database (using DatabasePopulator class in Spring). It works, but schema.sql is imported every time the application starts (establishes a connection).

My goal is to load it after database creation only. If a connection is established to already existing database, I want to skip it.

From what I've read:

- H2 provides a way to init database using RUNSCRIPT in jdbc url (loads every time, not what I want).
- Spring Data JPA and Hibernate allow database initialization by autogenerating DDL (not what I want, I have to use schema.sql) or loading schema.sql, but that one only works when spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property is set to either create or create-drop, which is also not what I want, because I have database in a file and it must not be deleted every time the application starts.

So my question is: **How to load schema.sql on database creation only, without manually checking if the database exists? Is it even possible?**

Comment: You could use spring-boot‘s `spring.datasource.continue-on-error` (eg execution of the schema.sql fails because a table already exists) - or use a migration tool such as flyway or liquibase.

Comment: The thing is, schema.sql also contains drop table if exists statements (don't ask me why, I've joined this project recently :P) so `spring.datasource.continue-on-error` is out of the question as well sadly. Currently I am checking if database exists manually and if it does, I'm not firing the populator. It works, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way. I can't use any migration tool either. Thanks for your comment!